# R: Tabla de distribución de frecuencias

Tags: r

He calculado las frecuencias absolutas y relativas, incluyendo las acumuladas, para un vector:

```
crias = c(4, 7, 2, 8, 6, 7, 2, 2, 9, 5, 5, 4, 5, 2, 6, 4, 7, 8, 4, 8)

n_crias = table(crias)
N_crias = cumsum(n_crias)
f_crias = prop.table(n_crias)
F_crias = cumsum(f_crias)
```

Ahora me gustaría presentar esta información de manera que fuera fácil de leer, tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a almacenar todas las variables en una lista, pero, para empezar, me repite todos los niveles variable a variable, lo cual resulta redundante.

¿Qué podría hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre que lo más sencillo es trabajar con un `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(i=seq(n_crias),
                 n_crias,
                 N_crias,
                 as.vector(f_crias),
                 F_crias,
                 row.names = NULL
)

# Renombramos las columnas originales
colnames(df) <- c("i", "xi", "ni", "Ni", "fi", "Fi")

df 

  i xi ni Ni   fi   Fi
2 1  2  4  4 0.20 0.20
4 2  4  4  8 0.20 0.40
5 3  5  3 11 0.15 0.55
6 4  6  2 13 0.10 0.65
7 5  7  3 16 0.15 0.80
8 6  8  3 19 0.15 0.95
9 7  9  1 20 0.05 1.00
```

Comment: ¿Sería posible eliminar la primer columna sin título que repite los valores xi?

Comment: La primer columna, en realidad no es tal, se trata de los nombres de fila y sí se puede quitar: `row.names = NULL`, revisa mi última edición

Comment: He eliminado `seq(n_crias)` porque añade igualmente una columna con números del 1 al 7.